# Google sheets cell as plain text from the API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, number-formatting, google-developers-console

I am trying to change cell format to `plain text` from `google api`: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate

Doing it directly from google drive gives me a completely different result than doing it from the API.

I add the following examples of what I am trying to do.

This is from the spreadsheet formatting:

1. This is the field I want to format as plain text

[image]

2. This is what I do

   Format > Number > Plain Text
3. This is the result:

[image]

This is what happens when I format it from the google API with the above JSON:

1. This is the field I want to format:

[image]

2. This is the XML that I am applying from the API:

   ````
        "requests": [
          {
            "repeatCell": {
              "range": {
                "sheetId": 3,
                "startColumnIndex": 2,
                "endColumnIndex": 3,
                "startRowIndex": 16,
                "endRowIndex": 17
              },
              "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "TEXT"
                  }
                }
              },
              "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
            }
          }
        ]
      }```
   ````
3. This is the result of applying the format from the API:

[image]

**My problem**: how can I get the same thing from the API as from the sheet? What do I have to change in the JSON to correctly apply the format?

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to check the behavior? Always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GabrielCarballo I just included an example of how I am doing the procedures

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361965/format-cells-in-google-sheets-from-api-v4 it seems that there is no direct way to directly set the text as plain text.